# Expressing basic number parser using >>=

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, parsec

I am working through the WikiBook "Write Yourself A Scheme in 48 Hours."

The Haskell library Parsec is being used to parse basic expressions, such as numbers (as shown in the code below).

```
import Lib
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)
import System.Environment

import Control.Monad

import Data.Typeable ( typeOf )

import Debug.Trace


data LispVal = Atom String 
             | List [LispVal] 
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal
             | Number Integer 
             | String String 
             | Bool Bool 
    deriving Show
-- ...
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = do
                x <- many1 digit
                return $ Number (read x)
```

One of the exercises in the book asks the reader to rewrite `parseNumber` using `>>=` notation instead. However, I keep running into scary-looking type mismatch errors. Can someone please show me how to rewrite the function using `>>=` notation? Or at least give me a hint?

Comment: The Haskell report shows how to desugar `do` expressions: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Haskell report has a section on [do notation](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) and how to "desugar" these `do` blocks.

If you write a `do` block as:

```
parseNumber = do
    x <- many1 digit
    return (Number (read x))
```

Then this is syntactically equivalent to:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = many1 digit >>= \x -> return (Number (read x))
```

or more elegant:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = many1 digit >>= return . Number . read
```

We however do not need to work with `>>=`. Indeed, if we want to apply a function on the item that will be constructed with the `Parser`, then we can use [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) or [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) for this:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = Number . read <$> many1 digit
```